# Errors regarding code meant to delete items in a list full of Strings

Tags: swift, string, list, textfield, delete-row

Right now I have code that fills a list with Strings that the user inputs. However, I am unable to remove anything from the list once it has been added. I have 2 errors in my code that I have below. One says Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols. The other says Value of type 'List>>' has no member 'onDelete'. Any help would be great

```
import SwiftUI

struct VarsityPercView: View {
@State private var usedWords = [String] ()
    @State private var rootWord = ""
    @State private var newWord = ""

    var body: some View {// Error 1 here
        NavigationView {
            HStack{
                TextField("Enter your word", text: $newWord, onCommit: addNewWord)
                List(usedWords, id: \.self){
                    Text($0)
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)// Error 2 here

            }

        .navigationBarTitle(rootWord)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
}
        //navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}
    func addNewWord(){

        let answer = newWord
        usedWords.insert(answer, at: 0)
        newWord = ""
        return

    }
  func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
         self.usedWords.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }

struct VarsityPercView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VarsityPercView()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Amaudi and welcome to stackoverflow!  It may be helpful if you include the line number to which each of the errors correspond.

Comment: Please share the entire error message(s).